# Make cursor corresponding array with multiple rows followed by same row id's

Tags: arrays, database, rows, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a DB in which id's are change after few rows, then same I'd in some rows then change I'd.  What I want that, the same I'd values will be populated listview's in one line, then when the Ids are same,  they are all in  one row. And thus the next rows populate with same rows which have same ID's.

My DB columns and rows  are as follows:

---

### Verse_id -------words_id----------words_ar------ translate_bn--

```
1-----------------------1---------------Mamun-----------Assistant---        
1-----------------------2--------------- Salam------------Operator------
1-----------------------3---------------John--------------Assistant------
2 ----------------------1--------------- Smith-------------Manager------
2-----------------------2---------------Roger--------------Director--------
3-----------------------1---------------Qoel---------------Helper---------- 
3-----------------------2---------------Saki---------------Mechanics-----
3-----------------------3----------------Ali-----------------Getman----------
```

I want this DB in three lines, as follows :   (listview):

```
1.     Mamun.           Salam             John 
       Assistant.       Operator.        Assistant 
------------------------------------------------------------------
2.     Smith.            Roger.  
       Manager.         Director 
------------------------------------------------------------------
3.      Qoel.            Saki.              Ali. 
        Helper.        Mechanics.          Getman
```

I have Tried in Two way : 
First :

```
private static final String PRIMARY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "bywords";
    private static final String FRIEND_ID = "verse_id";
    private static final String WORDS_ID = "words_id";
    private static final String WORDS_bN = "translate_bn";
    private static final String WORDS_AR = "words_ar";

private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ArrayList<String> friends;

    private ArrayList<String> trans1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        mContext = this;

        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  bywords", null);



        ListView list4=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list4)   ;

        String[] from = {WORDS_AR }; // _id mandatory
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.alquran_text};

        CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                mContext,
                R.layout.list_item,
                cursor,
                from,
                to,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);


        list4.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And Then Second :

```
    trans1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] allColumns2 = new String[] { FRIEND_ID,
                BN_TRANS };

        Cursor friendCursor2 = database.query(TABLE_NAME, allColumns2, null,
                null, null, null, null);


        if (friendCursor2 != null) {
            friendCursor2.moveToFirst();
        }
        //return friendCursor;


        if(!friendCursor2.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String name = friendCursor2.getString(1);
                trans1.add(name);
            } while (friendCursor2.moveToNext());
        }

        friendCursor2.close();





    String [] bntrans1= new String[trans1.size()];
                bntrans1 = trans1.toArray(bntrans1);





ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.layout.alert_row, seleted_route) {

                    ViewHolder holder;
                    Drawable icon;

                    class ViewHolder {
                        ImageView icon;
                        TextView title;
                        TextView title2;
                    }

                    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                                .getSystemService(
                                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        if (convertView == null) {
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                                    R.layout.alert_row, null);

                            holder = new ViewHolder();
                            //holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                            //      .findViewById(R.id.icon4);
                            holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.title4);
                            holder.title2 = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.title2);


                            convertView.setTag(holder);
                        } else {
                            // view already defined, retrieve view holder
                            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }

                        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iqra1); //this is an image from the drawables folder

                        holder.title.setText(seleted_route[position]);
                        holder.title2.setText(seleted_route[position]);
                        //holder.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

                        return convertView;
                    }
                };
```

By the second way I can populate two column in two text view in one rows. But what I want that the corresponding rows with same id of rows must  populate in one line of listview with verse I'd. The id's whataver are same in rows  may be 5, 10 or twenty rows same id. Whenever the same Id They are one line, When the Id change the newline begins.

Comment: Do you have some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see my Edit .

Comment: I have posted my code, bro, please take a look at it.  in this case I guess "custom cursor adapter " may solve the problem, But I don't know how can I do it.  please help if you can, in my criteria above.